# How to bypass TFS error regarding character path limits for directories that have been removed? (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, merge

I am using TFS to source control my c# ASP.NET MVC projects. I have a project called `ProjectA`, It has two branches (i.e `ProjectA` and `ProjectA-Dev`.) `ProjectA` is my production branch, and `ProjectA-Dev` is my development branch. `ProjectA-Dev` contains lots of new code for my project's upcoming release.

I am at a stage that I need to merge any change from production into dev. My production version received a few bug fixes while I was working on my next release in `ProjectA-Dev`. I want to merge the added bug fixes into my `ProjectA-Dev` branch.

To merge `ProjectA` into `ProjectA-dev`, I opened "Solution Control Explorer", right clicked on `ProjectA` then on "Branching and Merging" then on "Merge".

On the Source Control Merge Wizard I selected `$/TFS/ProjectA` in the source branch. I then selected `$/TFS/ProjectA-Dev` in the target branch. Then I hit "Next", selected "Latest Version", and hit "Finish".

The process runs for approximately 10 seconds and then it gives me this error [image: TF400959: The limited of 388 characters for a directory... was exceeded by the path for...]

The error makes complete sense. However, what is puzzling me is that the `node_modules` directory does not exist on either branch. Also, I removed the folder `node_modules` from my local projects.

I should also note that `node_modules` used to be in TFS, but then I removed it from TFS few weeks ago using changeset 20000. But, today, in the latest version, the folder `node_modules` does not exist on TFS. I also validated the same thing via the web portal.

I tried to remove the TFS cache locally by deleting the content of this folder `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache` but the issue still exists.

How can I bypass this error and correctly merge these changes?

Comment: I check-in my code via the "Team Explorer" pane. On each file you can right-click and "Compare with workspace version". Form there, I can see the changes I made. If you don't do hat and check-in your code, you will get a notification of your conflicts. You can then use the  Merge Tool.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee341461(v=expression.40).aspx

Comment: @MarkBeleski my issue is not a conflict. My issue is that TFS is complaining about a folder that does not even exists locally or on TFS. How can I even compare version for an item that does not exists?

Comment: Apart from your problem, you should add the node_modules folder to the .gitignore to avoid such issues in the first place (folder name too long), the package.json file being enough to recover dependencies.

Comment: I know this sounds dumb but did you look for the folder in Windows Explorer? Sometimes VS doesn't show everything...Or in the top bar of the Solution Explorer, select the "Show all files" button. If all else fails, I delete my local repository and resync it with TFS.

Comment: @MarkBeleski I already added `\node_modules` inside a file called `.tfignore`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to work after running 
`tf destroy "$/MyPath/To/Project/node_module"`

Answer (score 1):

TFS might not know what you changed (deleted node_modules files) and if the change might be relevant to the branch during a long changesets in branch projectA.

You could find the specific changeset which you deleted the node_modules files first. Then just use [tf merge command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/merge-command) with `/discard` option.

> **/discard** Does not perform the merge operation, but updates the merge
>   history to track that the merge occurred. This discards a changeset
>   from being used for a particular merge.

Sample command：

```
tf merge $/Project/SourceBranch $/Project/TargetBranch /discard /recursive /version:C56693~C56693
```

It discards changeset 56693. The version is a from ~ to, so you can discard multiple changesets at once. In your case discard the changeset till the specific changeset node_modules files deleted. When the command has finished, you still need to **check in the merge**.

After this just perform the normal merge action again.

Comment: Thanks for your help. On change set 20,000, I deleted the node_modules folder from multiple different projects (yes this is bad practice but is what happened.) I executed this command tf merge "$/ProjectA" $/ProjectA-Dev /discard /recursive /version:C20000~20000 that returned the following There are no changes to merge.